# Track down Memory leaks in a Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, memory, memory-leaks

I have created a Ruby XMPP Framework called [babylon](http://github.com/julien51/babylon/tree/master). I have then created a few applications with it and even though they run pretty smoothly, it seems that they're eating my computer memory bit by bit.

I suspected leaks, so first, I added this at some point in my code :

```
puts `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i
```

As suspected, the output kept increasing... slowly, but surely.

I tried to hunt the leaks with Dike, like [explained here](http://jan.flempo.com/2008/01/04/memory-leaks-in-ruby-18/).

Unfortunetely, Dike was not able to detect any leak. Even after it ran for a quite long time, it still returns the same objects.

So, how can I be sure that my framework is leaking, and not just taking some RAM until some maximum point and then starting to release it?

And then, how can I actually track the leaks and fix them?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good things about the [Ruby Memory Tracking API](http://softwareverify.com/ruby/customBuild/memtrack/index.html) but it is not free.

There is also a useful blog post for [using valgrind](http://www.idle-hacking.com/2008/05/ruby-extension-memory-leak-tracking/) to find ruby memory leaks.

There are other solutions for Ruby on Rails but it doesn't seem like you are using rails at all.

Comment: @Julein Genestoux, You got two solutions for the price of one.